# Inserting data in vuex-orm database that is already normalized

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-orm

Assuming the data i receive is already normalized, or at least the relations.
How can this data be inserted into the vuex-orm database?

Example JSON data:

```json
{
  "carmodel": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "M3",
      "manufacturer_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "a-class"
      "manufacturer_id": 2
    }
  ],
  "manufacturer": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "BMW"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Mercedes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Manufacturer Model and Carmodel are inserted like this:

```
Manufacturer.insert({ data: response.data.manufacturer })
CarModel.insert({ data: response.data.carmodel })
```

This example model will not work:

```js
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core'
import Manufacturer from '@/models/Manufacturer'

export default class CarModel extends Model {
  static entity = 'carModels'

  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      title: this.string(''),
      manufacturer: this.hasOne(Manufacturer, 'manufacturer_id')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think i got it. Instead of *this.hasOne* i have to use *belongsTo* and use the manufacturer_id from the same model:

```js
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core'
import Manufacturer from '@/models/Manufacturer'

export default class CarModel extends Model {
  static entity = 'carModels'

  static fields () {
    return {
      id: this.attr(null),
      title: this.string(''),
      manufacturer_id: this.attr(null),
      manufacturer: this.belongsTo(Manufacturer, 'manufacturer_id')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but this approach does not seem to work: `manufacturer` is always `null`.

Comment: @EerikSvenPuudist how are you retrieving the model that contains the `manufacturer`?